# I can't get GPS working with Google Maps on my Nexus 4

Tags: devices, gps

I have a Nexus 4 with Ubuntu 14.10 (r243) running on it. None of my installed apps can access GPS information.  OSM Touch says "No GPS available", and Google Maps says "Your location could not be determined."  I installed the SensorStatus app as well, but it fails to fill in any of the fields in the GPS screen, even though it says "Found supported backend" with a green check mark next to it.

I asked on #ubuntu-touch, and was told to "Go back to the original welcome screen and allow these apps to use GPS", but after a good deal of Googling, I was unable to figure out how to do that.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

From the indicator panel, to be sure to enable both the "Location detection" and the "GPS".
From setting> Security & Privacy> Location access> to select the "Using GPS, anonymized Wi-Fi and cellular network info."
Then reboot the phone.

It works for me: Google nexus 4, ubuntu-touch rtm 14.09.

Update: The stable-developers version: the Google maps could not determine  my precise location, and we don't have the option "Using GPS, anonymized Wi-Fi and cellular network info."

Source: the answer of Mr. Julia Palandri:
[GPS unvailable on aquaris E45](https://askubuntu.com/questions/603101/gps-unvailable-on-aquaris-e45)