# GPS location not working on BQ Ubuntu phone with Map applications

Tags: ubuntu-touch, phone, bq

I am having issues with GPS location ability with BQ Ubuntu phone, with the map applications. When I am on a wireless network this works fine. However when in a metro area with close to full carrier network signal, no good.

-I can access websites with the browser ok.
-confirmed that 'data roaming' 'location detection' & 'GPS' are selected.
-tested with three maps applications, google maps, here maps & whereis.
-these map applications can view areas If search manually, but still cannot find my location.

this is probably more of a hardware limitation than software.

thanks 
James

Answer (score 0):

> Please note that standalone GPS positioning is quite slow in acquiring
>   a fix. That is, without any additional help, the time from requesting
>   a position until the first actual fix is delivered may very well take
>   ~20 minutes depending on satellite visibility.
>
> That being said, we have enabled multiple ways of speeding up location
>   fixes. All of them require a non-roaming data connection, e.g., a WiFi
>   connection or a mobile data connection.

message from user83107

please refer to [GPS unvailable on aquaris E45](https://askubuntu.com/questions/603101/gps-unvailable-on-aquaris-e45)